# Floating action button no longer transparent

Tags: android, layout, transparency, transparent, floating-action-button

I am trying to make a floating action button in my android project.

So far i have [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20843558/Screenshot_2015-06-01-10-44-10.png) and that looks good.

The only problem is that when i go to a other part of my app and then go back to the fragment with the floating action button all of the sudden it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20843558/Screenshot_2015-06-01-10-34-28.png). The transparency is completely gone.

My layout xml looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.lightningworks.freek.hourkeeper.JobFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_new"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:id="@+id/jobNewButton"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And my circle drawable looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:top="8px">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3px"
                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px"
                    android:top="3px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>

<item >

    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#FFBB00" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">

                <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimary" />


            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>

</item>


</layer-list>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and why the first time the button is transparent.

Comment: There are many libraries for this you can use that. https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: Thank you for that link I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by Sandeep Singh solved my issue.

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton